# How to validate model address field with allowing enter button of keyboard?

Tags: .net, regex

I am trying the validate address field in `MVC model`, but not able to catch the enter key of keyboard

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_\., -]{0,100}$", 
                ErrorMessage = "only Alphabets and Selected Special Char")]
[StringLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Maximum 200 characters allowed")]

//[Display(Name = "Company Name")]
public string BillingAddress { get; set; }
```

There are allowable character in Regular expression, but not able to find the enter key char to put in to the model to allow multiline.

Comment: try using \r in regular expression. \r is for carriage return.

Comment: @vaibhavsilar IMO you should post it as answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `[\n\r]` in your regular expression

`\r` is for carriage return
`\n` is for newline character